# Is 恁 related to 您?

Tags: topolect, character-variant

I noticed that in Henan dialect people use 恁, nén in place of 你.

Some comments in this question:[Why in Chinese Bible (和合本), "you" was translated as "你" instead of "您"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/40144/why-in-chinese-bible-%e5%92%8c%e5%90%88%e6%9c%ac-you-was-translated-as-%e4%bd%a0-instead-of-%e6%82%a8?rq=1) note that 您, the polite form of 你, was originally a Northern Dialect address and only later acquired its status as a polite form of address. Presumably, Henan dialect would be included under the category of Northern Dialect.

I'm wondering if 恁 and 您 are related, given they have similar pronunciations. Could they have been originally variant characters for the same word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on "[汉典](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%81%81):

"恁"同“您” [you] 多见于早期白话.

- 恁不去出力，息生教娘娘和番?——马志远《汉宫秋》

Answer (score 1):

恁这是弄啥类，咋恁样嘞恁。 常用在早期或现在一些农家土语（方言）上。扩展一下，怹，tān：代指老人，尊称，“怹老人家”